# Access to images inside assembly file in custom control project

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I've been having troubles accessing to images inside assembly files in order to render them on the web.

I created a composite control to render a panel, I assigned gifs to some parts of the pannel, but it seems they are not accessible once I publish the website or hitting f5, I get a broken image icon where the images should appear.

This is how im trying to give permissions to the method to get the images inside the assembly :

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
```

But it does not work, this is an example of how im trying to access the images inside the assembly into that method :

```
(ColapseIconUrl == "") ? Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CompositeCustomControl.Images.icon_collapse.gif") : ColapseIconUrl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please ask if you want more info on the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at http://forums.asp.net/t/1227097.aspx/1 you need to change the "Build Action" from content to "Embedded Resource" you can do this by, selecting the item from within the solution explorer. Right clicking the item selecting "Properties"  then changing the "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource".

Hope that helps